# HSQL Trigger generates SQL Error: -458, SQLState: S1000 / java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: triggers, hsqldb

I have an HSQL version of an Oracle database schema to perform unit tests.

I need to update a column on update with current timestamp.

The trigger I have implemented is loaded without complaint by the hsql engine, but it crashes at runtime when I try to update rows.

Here is a sample test case that you can run in a project configured with spring and junit:

```
public class UtSqlTriggerTest {
    @Test public void testTrigger() throws SQLException {
        ResourceDatabasePopulator resourceDatabasePopulator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
        resourceDatabasePopulator.addScript(new InMemoryResource(
            "CREATE TABLE TEST (ID NUMERIC NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,DATA VARCHAR(200), LAST_UPDATE TIMESTAMP);\n" +

             "CREATE TRIGGER updTimestamp AFTER UPDATE OF DATA ON TEST\n" +
             "REFERENCING NEW AS newrow OLD AS oldrow\n" +
             "FOR EACH ROW\n" +
             "SET newrow.LAST_UPDATE = current_timestamp;"));

        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:file:/opt/db/testdb;shutdown=true", "SA", "");
        resourceDatabasePopulator.populate(connection);

        JdbcTemplate tjdbc = new JdbcTemplate(new SingleConnectionDataSource(connection, true));
        tjdbc.update("INSERT INTO TEST(ID, DATA) VALUES (0, 'HELLO')");
        tjdbc.update("UPDATE TEST SET DATA = 'HELLO WORLD' WHERE ID = 0");
        tjdbc.queryForObject("SELECT LAST_UPDATE FROM TEST WHERE ID = 0", Date.class);
    }               
}
```

What's wrong with this trigger ? Why it generated ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException ?

```
CREATE TRIGGER updateDateAjoutFichier AFTER UPDATE OF DATA ON TEST
REFERENCING NEW AS newrow OLD AS oldrow
FOR EACH ROW
SET newrow.LAST_UPDATE = current_timestamp;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run the CREATE TRIGGER in a SQL client you will see the following error message:

> attempt to assign to non-updatable column: LAST_UPDATE [SQL State=0U000, DB Errorcode=-2500]

This is because you are trying to modify a column in an `AFTER` trigger. Changing column values is only possible in a `BEFORE` trigger. So you should use:

```
CREATE TRIGGER updTimestamp BEFORE UPDATE OF DATA ON TEST
REFERENCING NEW AS newrow OLD AS oldrow
FOR EACH ROW
   SET newrow.LAST_UPDATE = current_timestamp;
```